# GUI with input csv and output table and plot png file

Tags: python, plotly, pysimplegui

I am creating a GUI where an input is a `csv file` and an output should be a table from the csv input file and the plots from the table values. User should be able to choose an input file and a place to save the output.

So far, i did this :

```
#GUI CSV TO TABLE/PLOT PNG FILE
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import csv
#import pandas as pd
#import plotly.express as px


def table_example(filename, directory): #define the function that creates a table from an input file
    if filename == '':
        return
    data = []
    header_list = []
    button = sg.popup_yes_no('Does this file have column names already?') #check if input file already has column names
    if filename is not None: 
        with open(filename, "r") as infile:
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            if button == 'Yes':  #if yes, take the column names from the file
                header_list = next(reader)
            try:
                data = list(reader)
                if button == 'No':  #if not, name the columns as column0,column1 etc.
                    header_list = ['column' + str(x) for x in range(len(data[0]))]
            except:
                sg.popup_error('Error reading file')
                return
            
    #create a plot 
    #df=pd.read_csv(filename)
    #fig=px.line(df,x = header_list[1],y = header_list[2], title = 'Plot Example')
    #fig.show() #FIX THIS PART TO GET THE PLOT

    
    #create a window to show the table
    layout = [[sg.Table(values=data,
                        headings=header_list,
                        max_col_width=25,
                        auto_size_columns=True,
                        justification='right',
                        num_rows=min(len(data), 20))]]


    window = sg.Window('Table', layout, grab_anywhere=False)
    event, values = window.read()

    window.close()


#create a widow for choosing and input file and output folder
sg.theme('SystemDefault')

layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Input File Path: ")], [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.T("")], [sg.Text("Output File Path: ")], [sg.Input(),sg.FolderBrowse()],
          [sg.T("")], [sg.Button('Begin!')]
         ]

window = sg.Window('File Browser', layout, size=(600,250))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    #end program if user closes window
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED: 
        break
    #start with function table_example() to create a table from an input is user clicks on Begin!
    if event == "Begin!":
        filename, directory = values[0], values[1]    # 0 and 1 are keys of dictionary `values`
        table_example(filename,directory) #take input data and create a table

window.close()


#TO DOS:
#create plot
#save table(left side) and plot(right side) in the file and in the output folder from users choice
```

Now the problem is that i cannot get the plot, and don't know what i have to do. And also, how to get the table and the file saved in one file which will be saved in the directory that user chose as an output file path?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Height of window is too small to show button `Beginn!`, set it to `size=(600, 300)`

No key set for `sg.Input`, so the keys will be 0 and 1 for your `sg.Input`.
You can get the filename and directory in your event loop by

```py
if event == "Beginn!":
    filename, directory = values[0], values[1]    # 0 and 1 are keys of dictionary `values`
    table_example(filename, directory)
```

Maybe you can check demo programs how to plot a png file, maybe PIL Image, ImageDraw, or Matplotlib, or others.

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms

Comment: Thanks, i changed my code, and got the table, but still have problems with plot and with saving both in one file. Can you help with that?

Comment: After figure drawn, you can call `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` to save figure to png https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html